# Is using database queries inside a jinja2 template a good practice?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I was wondering if it's okay to use database queries inside a template, for example, like this:

```html
{% for thread in threads %}
<div class="thread">
    <div class="thread__op">
        {% with opening = thread.posts.first() %} {# thread.posts.first() is a query. #}
        {{ opening.title }}
        {{ opening.message }}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against this, as you don't want to be passing in the query to your template. I would advise that you just create a list of dictionaries from your query on the server side:

`openings = [{'title': 'title1', 'message': 'message1'},...]`

You can then pass this to your template using:

`return render_template('page.html', openings=json.dumps(openings))`

Then you can simply iterate through your openings as above, except you will not need the `{% with opening = thread.posts.first() %}`. So it should just be:

```
{% for opening in openings %}
<div class="thread">
    <div class="thread__op">
        {{ opening.title }}
        {{ opening.message }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

In general, it's best to keep the data you are passing into your templates as simple as possible. If you are going to do work on the server-side, you might as well get it as simple as possible when you pass it to your page.